# React, fetch from multiple endpoints and render data in table

Tags: rest, reactjs

I have rest api and I'm writing some frontend for this (1st time using react). I need to get data from few endpoints and  show it in table.  <s>For that moment I'm getting data from one endpoint and rendering it and it's working fine. Url's to endpoints are looking like:
    http://localhost/app.php/api/endpointname/123?from=2017-05-05&to=2017-05-07</s>

Endpoint name will be one of this: visits, visitors, entrances.

All endpoints are returning objects looking like this:

```
2017-05-05: 5,
2017-05-06: 1,
2017-05-07: 4,
```

How to render it after that, it's good idea to write some model component getting data from all endpoints and returning one array from this?

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visits: [],
            visitors: [],
            entrances: [],
            type: props.type,
            reportFor: props.reportFor,
            websiteId: props.websiteId,
            date: props.date,
            dateTo: props.dateTo
        };
    }

    GetUrl(endpoint) {
        let date;
        if (this.state.type === 'daily') {
            date = 'from=' + this.state.date + '&to=' + this.state.dateTo;
        } else if (this.state.type === 'hourly') {
            date = 'day=' + this.state.date;
        }

        return 'http://localhost/app.php/api/'
            + this.state.type + '/'
            + endpoint + '/'
            + this.state.websiteId + '?'
            + date;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let endpoints = ['visits', 'visitors', 'entrances'];

        endpoints.map((endpoint) =>
            fetch(this.GetUrl(endpoint))
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    this.setState({
                    [endpoint]: responseJson
                    });
                }).catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            })
        )
    }

    render() {
        let visits = this.state.visits;
        let visitors = this.state.visitors;
        let headers = ['Date', 'Visits', 'Entrances', 'Visitors'];

        return (
            <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 column">
                <table className="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {headers.map((header) => <th>{header}</th>)}
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {Object.entries(visits).map(([date, visit]) => <tr>
                        <td>{date}</td>
                        <td>{visit}</td>
                    </tr>)}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App type='daily' reportFor='visits' websiteId='5d918b7d-91ca-4f15-95df-fd8c71a6c2b9' date='2017-05-05'
                 dateTo='2017-05-10'/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I will be grateful for advice how I can refactor this code maybe for smaller components or something. It's my 1st react app and I don't feel how to separate components.

Greetings

Edit: Now I'm getting data from all endpoints but still don't know how to render result in right way.

Comment: why don't you iterate through it. Wouldn't that be easier

Comment: You mean iterate through endpoints? Now I did this but still don't know how to render result in one table.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine the data first, and then map through one array.

```
render() {
    // Combine arrays of data
    let combinedData = [...this.state.visits, ...this.state.visitors];
    let headers = ['Date', 'Visits', 'Entrances', 'Visitors'];

    return (
        <div className="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 column">
            <table className="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    {headers.map((header) => <th>{header}</th>)}
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {Object.entries(combinedData).map(([date, visit]) => 
                <tr>
                    <td>{date}</td>
                    <td>{visit}</td>
                </tr>)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```